# PropTypes not validating in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setup some type validation on my components, but none of the type checks seem to be working. If I use the ES6 class notation like so :

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    IdoNotExist: PropTypes.element.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
        );
  }
}
```

There are no warnings that appear in my console.

I am also working in DEV mode (not production), and I have also tried doing it like this :

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  IdoNotExist:PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

Nothing seems to work :(

*On a side note : is it possible to make more 'harder' type checks in react? I do not just want a 'warning' when a proptype check fails. I would like an exception thrown and the 'render' function not be called. Is it possible to do this in react?*

Comment: For the side note, you will need to add some form of static type checking then. Check out Typescript or Flow. Both very popular.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek why should he need to do it?

Comment: He doesn't need to do it. It's just the answer if he wants to, considering the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `defaultProps` property, but this only initializes the props values. For validation, use `propTypes` property on your component. Obviously, you conflated those two properties and you are using `defaultProps` in a way `propTypes` should be defined.